# Dajax example "Multiply Machine!" not working. Help

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates

Trying to learn Dajax, so decided to try out examples. But I am stuck with the "multiply" example. I have no clue what is wrong. Below is the code.

ajax.py:(its placed inside 'blog' app)

```
from dajax.core import Dajax
from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_functions

def multiply(request, a, b):
    dajax = Dajax()
    result = int(a) * int(b)
    dajax.assign('#result','value',str(result))
    return dajax.json()

dajaxice_functions.register(multiply)
```

index.html:

```
{% load dajaxice_templatetags %}
<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Blog</title>
        {% dajaxice_js_import %}
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
             function calculate(){
                Dajaxice.blog.multiply(Dajax.process,{'a':$('a').value,'b':$('b').value})
              }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <input type="text" name="a" value="5" id="a"> x
        <input type="text" name="b" value="6" id="b"> =
        <input type="text" name="result" value="" id="result">
        <input type="button" name="caculate" value="Let's Multiply!" id="caculate" onclick="calculate()">

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what's the error you have? it's a JS error? What version of dajax an dajaxice are you using?

Comment: No error. Just that the result text field is empty. Multiplied value does not appear. I am using the latest version of dajax n dajaxice. Do i need to use any JS framework(jquery or prototype)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should [install dajaxice](http://docs.dajaxproject.com/dajaxice/installation.html) properly. Then, if you are using Dajax you should [install Dajax](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax/wiki/installation) too.

Reading your code seems that dajaxice is correctly installed but you haven't installed Dajax or (at least) you have not linked your dajax-flavoured js.

If you are using Dajax (you are using Dajax) you should choose a framework between Prototype, jQuery, Dojo or mootols and add it to your page, also you need to link the [framework.dajax.core.js](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax/tree/master/src) to your page.

The rest of the installation seems to be already done.